# how to enter manually a Python dataframe with daily dates in a correct format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to (manually) create in Python a dataframe with daily dates (in column 'date') as per below code.
But the code does not provide the correct format for the daily dates, neglects dates (the desired format representation is below).
Could you please advise how I can correct the code so that the 'date' column is entered in a desired format?
Thanks in advance!

```
------------------------------------------------------
desired format for date column

2021-03-22    3
2021-04-07    3
2021-04-18    3
2021-05-12    0

------------------------------------------------------
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": [2021-3-22, 2021-4-7, 2021-4-18, 2021-5-12],
"x": [3, 3, 3, 0 ]})
df1
    date    x
0   1996    3
1   2010    3
2   1999    3
3   2004    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python wants to interpret the numbers in the sequence `2021-3-22` as a series of mathematical operations `2021 minus 3 minus 22`.

If you want that item to be stored as a string that resembles a date you will need to mark them as string literal datatype (`str`), as shown below by encapsulating them with quotes.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": ['2021-3-22', '2021-4-7', '2021-4-18', '2021-5-12'],
"x": [3, 3, 3, 0 ]})
```

The results for the date column, as shown here indicate that the date column contains elements of the `object` datatype which encompasses `str` in pandas. Notice that the strings were created exactly as shown (`2021-3-22` instead of `2021-03-22`).

```
0    2021-3-22
1     2021-4-7
2    2021-4-18
3    2021-5-12
Name: date, dtype: object
```

IF however, you actually want them stored as `datetime` objects so that you can do datetime manipulations on them (i.e. determine the number of days between two dates OR filter by a specific month OR year) then you need to convert the values to `datetime` objects.

This technique will do that:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
```

The results of this conversion are Pandas `datetime` objects which enable nanosecond precision (I differentiate this from Python `datetime` objects which are limited to microsecond precision).

```
0   2021-03-22
1   2021-04-07
2   2021-04-18
3   2021-05-12
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Notice the displayed results are now formatted just as you would expect of `datetimes` (`2021-03-22` instead of `2021-3-22`).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed reply!

Comment: @Champion if this reply is helpful to you, please Accept the answer and please consider also upvoting the answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would want to create the series as a datetime and use the following codes when doing so as strings, more info here [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.to_datetime(["2021-3-22", "2021-4-7", "2021-4-18", "2021-5-12"]),
"x": [3, 3, 3, 0 ]})
```

Comment: thank you very much,!

Comment: @Champion no problem! If this answered your question please mark or upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the both answers were very useful and replied to my question (every one proposing a different angle to the solution), unfortunately it seems I can put only one answer as a final solution(.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I often use `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))` to copy/paste tabular-looking data into a `DataFrame` (for example, from SO questions).

Example:

```py
import io
import re
import pandas as pd

def df_read(txt, **kwargs):
    txt = '\n'.join([s.strip() for s in txt.splitlines()])
    return pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(re.sub(r'  +', '\t', txt)), sep='\t', **kwargs)


txt = """
date      value
2021-03-22    3
2021-04-07    3
2021-04-18    3
2021-05-12    0
"""

df = df_read(txt, parse_dates=['date'])

>>> df
        date  value
0 2021-03-22      3
1 2021-04-07      3
2 2021-04-18      3
3 2021-05-12      0

>>> df.dtypes
date     datetime64[ns]
value             int64
dtype: object
```